# Tensorflow object detection model train is creating no checkpoints on GCP

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-cloud-platform

We are trying to train Tensorflow object detection model on GCP.
After following all necessary steps from below url, we have started training on GCP with out any error. But no check points were created under train directory. We have given built lot of time with different region but no luck.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine

This is the command we have used to start training.

> 

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_eval_`date +%s` \
    --job-dir=gs://car-ml/train \
    --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
    --module-name object_detection.eval \
    --region asis-east1 \
    --scale-tier BASIC_GPU \
    -- \
    --checkpoint_dir=gs://car-ml/train \
    --eval_dir=gs://car-ml/eval \
    --pipeline_config_path=gs://car-ml/data/faster_rcnn_resnet101_voc07.config
```

Even in the log file also, training steps has been started.
Like below.

[image]

Job details are:

[image]

Comment: can you show contents of the .config, Also you wrote     --module-name object_detection.eval \
you mean .train

Comment: @Aniruddha, did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: No I did not able to solve it. But now a days I am not getting this issue anymore. May be due to new version Tensor-flow it has been solved. not sure.